# apt-cache show bash script

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I'm trying to write a bash script that will ask `echo "What programme do you want to see?"` and then give the answer as 'foo', so that 'foo' can be read by the line which says `apt-cache show foo|grep -i description -A 8`.

But how to do it, please?

I've got the echo line as above, but haven't a clue  as to what to do from there. This is to be used on Debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not too hard.

```
echo "What program do you want to see?"
read program
apt-cache show "$program" | grep -i description -A 8
```

See: [Catching user input](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html). In general, if you're new to Bash scripting, try to read a few guides first. Many of the basics (assigning variables, getting user input, output, variable substition) are covered very well in the [Bash Beginners Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/index.html).